# normalize array produces one empty slot at first index

Tags: javascript, json, redux, normalizr

I am new to React, Redux and normalizr. I'm trying to normalize my fetched data using **normalizr**.

Given this JSON:

```
   {'teams': [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nom": "Team1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nom": "Team2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nom": "Team3"
    }]}
```

I would like to apply the following normalization schema with normalizr:

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const teamSchema = new schema.Entity('teams');
const preloadedStateSchema = { teams: [ teamSchema ] };
const normalizedData = normalize(preloadedState, preloadedStateSchema);
```

What I expect:

```
{
    entities: {
        teams: {
            1: {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "Team1"
            },
            2: {
                "id": 2,
                "nom": "Team2"
            },
            3: {
                "id": 3,
                "nom": "Team3"
            }
        },
    result:{
        teams: [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

What I get:

```
{
    entities: {
        teams: {
            1: **<EMPTY SLOT>**
            2: {
                "id": 2,
                "nom": "Team2"
            },
            3: {
                "id": 3,
                "nom": "Team3"
            }
        },
    result:{
        teams: [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

Where does this "empty slot" comes from ? How to fix this ?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code, run it and it works as expected without any issues

Comment: You're right, it works. It seems to be a display bug of Firebug